# Which optional parameters do improve the accuracy of a google geolocation request result?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, gsm

I am using gsm cell data to get the current device position. To do this I use the [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/). All fields seem to be optional in the first part of the needed JSON parameters (URL: https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_key):

```
{
 "homeMobileCountryCode": 310,
 "homeMobileNetworkCode": 410,
 "radioType": "gsm",
 "carrier": "Vodafone",
 "cellTowers": [
 // See the Cell Tower Objects section below.
 ],
 "wifiAccessPoints": [
 // See the WiFi Access Point Objects section below.
 ]
}
```

Do the first 4 parameters homeMCC, homeMNC, radio Type and carrier have any influences on the accuracy? or the response time? I could not make out any differences.

Answer (score 0):

I can believe that the Google database of cell IDs is organised by carrier and network type, so there might in theory be a quicker response if you supply these parameters, but it would surely be negligible.  Can't think of a technical reason why it would need to know your home operator details too.  The only information these parameters would give them is (1) whether you're roaming or not and (2) any stored information that they might be holding about individual operators.  Does Google have special agreements with any operators?